# using @variable to @import another LESS file

Tags: css, variables, import, less

I'd like to use my @variable (@variable: "file.less") to import file.less to main .less.

I tried this way:

```
@var: 'file.less';
@import @var
```

or this way:

```
@import "@var"
```

or:

```
@import "@{var}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@imports are handled before @variables, so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the  beta for LESS 1.4.0. It should be able to handle variables in @import statements.

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/410

```
// An example from the issue for this feature:
@theme: winter;
@import "@{theme}/theme.less";
```

The beta is available for node via:

```
npm install -g less@beta
```

Or for the browser at https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.4.0-beta.js

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
@import url(@var);
```

?

---

Nah, that doesn't seem to work.